# Text input box not showing properly in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, input

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const[ID, setId] = useState("");

  const handleChange = event => {
    setId(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div className='IdParent'>
      <div className='some'>
        <label for="Id">Enter ID: </label> 
        <input
          id="IdFileld"
          name="IdFileld"
          type="text"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={ID}
        /> 
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

I'm trying to create a simple login from, but the placeholder of form is not displaying correctly.

Comment: There is no `placeholder` attribute in your code's <input>?

Comment: What placeholder are you referring to? What form are you referring to? Is the complete [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

As Chris Said.. You Need to add Placeholder in your Input Element..

```
        <input
          id="IdFileld"
          name="IdFileld"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter the Id"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={ID}
            />
```